# How to refresh the textbox text when tabs are Changed in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabs, textbox

Well in my WPF application I am using Tab Control which has around 5 tabs. The view of each tab is a user control which I add via a tool box.

**Main Xaml File:**

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
        <TabItem Header="Device Control" Name="Connect">
            <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" Name="scrollViewer1" Width="Auto">
                <my:ConnectView Name="connectView1" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="I2C">
            <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" Name="scrollViewer2" Width="Auto">
                <my1:I2CControlView Name="i2CControlView1" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Voltage">
                <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" Name="scrollViewer3" Width="Auto">
                    <my2:VoltageView Name="voltageView1" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

If you notice each view ie.e `Connect`, `I2C` and `Voltage` is a user control which has a view, viewmodel and model class :)

Each of these views have set of textboxes in their respective xaml files.

**Connect.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding Box}", Name="hello" />
    // Some more textboxes
</Grid>
```

**I2c.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding I2CBox}", Name="helI2c" />
    // Some more textboxes
</Grid>
```

**Voltage.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding VoltBox}", Name="heVoltllo" />
    // Some more textboxes
</Grid>**
```

By default I have set the text of these textboxes to some value. Lets say "12" "13" "14" respectively in my view model classes. My main requirement is to set the text of these textboxes present in each user control to get refreshed when I change the tab.

**Description:**

Lets say Connect View is displayed: Value of Textbox is 12 and I edit it and change it to 16. Now I click on I2C tab and then I go back to Connect tab, I want the textbox value to get refreshed back to the initial value i.e. 12.

To be precise, is their a method called visibilitychanged() which I can write in all my user control classes, where I can set the value of these Ui components whenever tabs are changed?

Please help :)

Comment: You can set it via code behind, in view.xaml.cs file.

Comment: @kuperspb: I would like to do it in my viewmodel class :) Do you know how can we do it that way? :)

Comment: Yes. You can use EventToCommand behavior, if you have it in your mvvm library. We using Catel mvvm, so we have this:
http://catel.catenalogic.com/index.htm?behaviors_eventtocommand.htm

Any way you need to do some work in code behind.

Comment: Well I don want to use Catel for it. Isn't their any general approach ???

Comment: AFAIK - no. Your task is much more closer to UI than to ViewModel logic.

Comment: @kuperspb: Well can you elaborate it using a code how to achieve it? :) I would appreciate that :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, for example. We have simple WPF app.
Main window:

```
<Window x:Class="tabs.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:tabs" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
            <TabItem Header="1">
                <my:Tab1/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="2">
                <my:Tab2/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Tab1 is just default template from VS, so no code here.
Tab2:

```
<UserControl x:Class="tabs.Tab2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="asd" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see we have event handler for TabControl_SelectionChanged event. In code behind of mainwindow we have:

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source is TabControl)
    {
        TabItem tabitem = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;
        if (tabitem == null)
            return;

        Tab2 tab2 = tabitem.Content as Tab2;
        if (tab2 == null)
            return;

        tab2.textBox1.Text = "zxczxczxczxc";
    }
}
```

Something like this. You can call Reinit method instead of setting value of textbox.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. This looks promising. Well I wouldnt like to change textbox text. I would ideally call a method which sets the value of these textboxes :)

Comment: You even can call your ViewModel method or update ViewModel properties. But i think this is not important. Anyway view only modifies data for user expirience and not touching view model logic and algorithms.

`XxxViewModel vm = tab2.DataContext as XxxViewModel;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do data binding to the TabControl "SelectedTab" or "SelectedIndex" properties. so when ever user changes tab your setter in view model will be called, there you can reset the text box property bindings..

Edit:

Here is a sample

**XAML:**

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding TabIndex}">
            <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue1}" Height="20" Width="200"></TextBox>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue2}" Height="20" Width="200"></TextBox>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 3">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue3}" Height="20" Width="200"></TextBox>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

**Properties and Method In ViewModel:**

```
private int tabIndex;
        public int TabIndex
        {
            get { return tabIndex; }
            set
            {
                tabIndex = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TabIndex");

                ResetTextBoxes();
            }
        }

        private void ResetTextBoxes()
        {
            TextValue1 = "12";
            TextValue2 = string.Empty;
            TextValue3 = "default";
        }

        private string textValue1;
        public string TextValue1
        {
            get { return textValue1; }
            set
            {
                textValue1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TextValue1");
            }
        }

        private string textValue2;
        public string TextValue2
        {
            get { return textValue2; }
            set
            {
                textValue2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TextValue2");
            }
        }

        private string textValue3;
        public string TextValue3
        {
            get { return textValue3; }
            set
            {
                textValue3 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TextValue3");
            }
        }
```

Comment: yeah this is what I was looking for :) Would appreciate if you could elaborate with a code please :)

Comment: Mind you, Textboxes are part of my user control which is a separate project in my solution. So you mean `ResetTextBoxes();` should be called in each viewmodel class of my different user controls where I can perform the operation???